# PDF viewer with print option using pyqt5 or other module

Tags: python, linux, windows, qt, pyqt5

I need to show the user a PDF file with the option to print it, and I've seen that pyqt5 has an option to do so, with a pretty interface ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbomq.png)), but I've tried many times with no result at all. The closest I've got was when I watched this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22cDr5zdiP4&t=155s, I tried something similar, as I use PyQt5 instead of pyside but they are similar, and also using PyQtWebEngine instead of PyQtWebKit as it is deprecated, but I just get a simple view window with no options [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLvo1.png).

code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

# pip install PyQtWebEngine

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
web.load(QUrl('table_with_headers_on_every_page.pdf'))
web.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note: This script/app should work on linux and windows

edit: I also get this error when scrolling: `js: Uncaught Error: Assertion failed`

Comment: maybe the URL is invalid ... where does the pdf file reside?

Comment: I moved the file to the desktop and now it shows it, but with no options, just a simple view edit: (I placed the link of the photo in the post)

Comment: maybe with also `self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PdfViewerEnabled, True)`  in PyQt6

Comment: @cards No, I got the same simple view window

Comment: just for curiosity, where did you get the information about the "pretty interface"? In your code there is no trace of it... that's why you get the standard

Comment: in a YouTube video (I placed the link in the post) and in some forums, and as I see its like the print preview dialog, that you can get using QPrintPreviewDialog

Comment: @Cattivellio The video repeatedly tells you that you must install a suitable pdf reader plugin on your system (otherwise you will likely just get some basic default version).

Comment: you need to write the full path of that file from the disk